# Aws git access/curl issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab, ubuntu-16.04, private-subnet

I am having something strange using AWS subnet with ubuntu instances.

I have create the public/private subnet schema with one ubuntu instance on the private one. Everything is working smoothly, I can git clone, curl...

However when creating any other ubuntu instance on the private subnet within the same VPC, I can't use git at all, even a simple curl to https://gitlab.com is not working (getting no answer).

I tried an other url like google and got a successful result.

Do you have an idea why I am getting this behaviour and specially only for gitlab?

Appreciate your help

Comment: Are they in the same security group?

Comment: Hi, 
Yes they are in the same security group. What's changing is the subnet but within the same VPC.

Comment: If you've already checked the route tables and ensured that there is http access on the neccessary ports, set up a VPC flow log and check the rejected traffic logs. It will let you know why it's not working